# How to make a naive datetime an aware datetime using pandas to_datetime() method

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timezone-offset, datetimeoffset

I have tried to make a `datetime object` selected from my dataframe (with a time column: `(Time_utc)` in Unix time), an aware datetime using `to_datetime()` method in pandas, but I don't seem to know how. I compared my output `(out)` with the Unix time converter online tool, and I see that what I indeed have is a naive datetime object.

I tried the following steps:

`import pandas as pd`

`df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time_utc, origin='unix', unit='s')`

Printed my results as:

`print(df.date_time[0])`

`out: 2021-08-13 13:27:48`

`Result from unixtimeconverter online tool:

```
Fri Aug 13 2021 13:27:48 GMT+0000
Fri Aug 13 2021 15:27:48 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

How do I make my `out` to be an aware datetime?

Comment: How is your input formatted? Did you try to set keyword `utc=True`?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried adding `utc=True` in the `to_datetime()` method and I get, after printing
`print(df.date_time[0])`: ```2021-08-13 13:27:48+00:00```
Also, if I check for the tzinfo(), it now shows it's UTC aware time:

Comment: Also, if I check for the tzinfo(), it now shows it's UTC aware time: 
```print(df.date_time[0].tzinfo)```: 
`out:` `UTC`.
But the offset is still +00:00. How do I get it to +02:00?

Comment: You can set a timezone. +02:00 could be "Europe/Berlin" for instance. Command would be `df['date_time'].dt.tz_convert("Europe/Berlin")`

Comment: Wow! Works like magic! Thanks so much @FObersteiner